# How to make thicker axis marks with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, matplotlib

I'm trying to print out a pdf with a graph, but the number denoting the marks on the axis are too small. Anyone know how to increase the fontsize?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 import matplotlib as plt
 plt.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=15)
```